# Automatic build not recognizing python

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Sublime Text 2, works fine if I manually set the build to Python but otherwise throws this error:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  ['py.test']]
[dir:  C:\Users\ZekeSSD\Dropbox\Fall 2013\6.006\Pset1]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64....
[Finished]
```

It works fine with my other builds. I have python in my path. Any ideas why it isn't working automatically?

Comment: is the file you're trying to build named `py.test`?

Comment: no. maybe the automatic build code hard coded this in for some weird reason? how can I open it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Change in the build file py.test -> py.test.exe and voila!.

Comment: Ooooh and where is this file? I've been searching for a while and I always get frustrated and give up. Sort of what path would it be most likely in?

Comment: If you can run py.test in a terminal and is ok, you can run py.test.exe. When you install `py.test`, `py.test.exe` is installed in the same path (`c:\Python27\Scripts`). Use `py.test.exe` in Sublime

Comment: yeah that's the thing, i don't have py.test in my Scripts folder

Comment: Try `c:\>easy_install -U pytest` for upgrade and check `c:\>Python27\Scripts` directory for `py.test.exe`.

Comment: All good on the upgrade but still there is no py.test.exe in the Scripts folder.